# Logging in website with python

Tags: python

I am trying to log into website with my username and password but I just cannot seem to get it working. Right now I am testing by using the website. If I am able to log in, I should be able to find the bit that says The SnowBomb Platinum Membership. If I am not able to login, I should find the lost_password text in the source code.

This is what I have:

```
info = {
    'USERNAME' : 'username',
    'PASSWORD' : 'password',
    #'submit' : 'login'   don't know if i need this
}

def main():
    r = requests.post('http://www.snowbomb.com/my-account-2', data = info)  #logged in
    request = requests.get('http://www.snowbomb.com/my-account-2')
    if 'lost_password' in  request.content:
        print 'Was not able to log in'
        print 'lost_password' in request.content
    else:
        if 'The SnowBomb Platinum Membership' in request.content:
            print 'Logged in'
            print 'The SnowBomb Platinum Membership' in request.content #--> when it works

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the form in the source code when asking user to log in:

```
<form method="post" class="login">
            <p class="form-row form-row-first">
                <label for="username">Username <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="username" id="username" />
            </p>
            <p class="form-row form-row-last">
                <label for="password">Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input class="input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
            </p>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <p class="form-row">
                <input type="hidden" id="_n" name="_n" value="a046c51363" /><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/my-account-2/" /><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.snowbomb.com/my-account"/>
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="login" value="Login" />
                <a class="lost_password" href="http://www.snowbomb.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword&#038;redirect_to=http://www.snowbomb.com">Lost Password?</a>
            </p>
        </form>
```

Comment: Instead of these two lines: `r = requests.post('http://www.snowbomb.com/my-account-2', data = info)
    request = requests.get('http://www.snowbomb.com/my-account-2')`, use this: `request = requests.get('http://www.snowbomb.com/my-account-2', auth = info)`

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi I get the error `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: `if 'The SnowBome Platinum Membership' in request.content`: is that a typo you made just in the question, or are you checking for the wrong string in your code?

Comment: @NeilVass sorry that was a typo

Comment: I'm really sorry, I didn't realize that `info` is a dictionary; define `info` as a tuple, like this: `info = ("username", "password")`, then use the commands that I've provided before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever there is a successful login, the website sets cookies in the browser. We need to send these cookies with all further requests, only then the website will recognise you each time.

You can do this using `urllib`, `urllib2` and `cookielib`. You can also do the same using `requests` and `sessions`.

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
url = "http://www.snowbomb.com/my-account-2"
login_request = s.post(url, data=payload)
print login_request.text
logged_in_request = c.get(url)
print logged_in_request.text
```

Comment: would this still work if the login url and the protected url are the same? The website i am dealing with has 2 different views with the same URL depending if the user logged in or not

Comment: Almost all websites have same url, but different views for logged in and guest users. But are you sure, the url on which login request is posted is the same? Can you give me the website link, if its not a problem.

Comment: `http://www.snowbomb.com/my-account-2` the html will change depending whether a user is logged in or not

Comment: @Liondancer Kindly close the question by accepting the answer, if it worked for you.